# Extract only numbers from a string with punctuation and spaces in R?

Tags: python, regex, r

How would I extract only the numbers using a regular expression from the following string:

```
+1 Ab_Cd- 001 234.txt`
```

Such that I return:

```
1001234
```

I have a data frame with a vector of such strings. I'm trying to do the above in both R and Python. I'm more familiar with R's `stringr` and `gsub()` from `base`. I've tried multiple expressions but can't get anything that works well.

Answer (score 6):

In R, you can use `gsub` to remove all non-digit `\\D` characters:

```
s <- "+1 Ab_Cd- 001 234.txt"
gsub("\\D+", "", s)
# [1] "1001234"
```

`sub` from `re` in python does similar thing:

```
import re
re.sub("\D+", "", "+1 Ab_Cd- 001 234.txt")
# '1001234'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R method with `strsplit` and `grepl` and `paste`

```
# split each character into a vector element
temp <- unlist(strsplit("+1 Ab_Cd- 001 234.txt", split=""))
# paste digit (numerical) characters together
paste(temp[grepl("[0-9]", temp)], collapse="")
```